# Send a base64 image in apex email

Tags: controller

1. I'm trying to send an email using apex Messaging class using the function 
   sendEmail(messages).
2. Its working fine and I received the mail correctly now the problem is with the 
   image part.
3. If I tried to send mail containing  tag it will be rendered in mail body 
   as base64 and visible in mail content as base 64 code not as an image.
4. Now the question is there any way to get an image in mail body using apex 
   messaging class.

   ```
   public void sendMail() {
   System.debug('The mailBody' + mailBody);
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.toAddresses = new String[] {
   'test@testdomain.com'
    };
   message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
   message.subject = 'Subject Test Message';
   message.HtmlBody = mailBody;
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new
   List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {message};

       Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
         if (results[0].success) {
         System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
       } else {
        System.debug('The email failed to send: ' + 
        results[0].errors[0].message);
       }
     }
   ```

In above code, mail body is an HTML mail body containing image tag with base64.

Comment: I do think you can get your base64 image in the email body, however, last time i checked there were some email clients which wouldn't display those images. It depends on your use case if that's an issue.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but the question is there a way to get images on those email client.

Comment: Not while sending the image as part of the message. The only thing you can do is to host the image somewhere, and link to it in the email. If its always the same image you're sending I'd suggest hosting it somewhere. If you want to use images from Salesforce then you could consider storing them as files, marking those public, and than using the public file url in an image tag. I think that should work, but I have never tried it.

Comment: No, not in this way I have to provide the screenshot custom functionality for the case feed using TinyMCE editor where a user can past any image may be a screenshot or any other image from there local machine and sent it to any email.

Comment: I think you only have two options. You can add the image as an normal attachment to the email, or you host the image somewhere (Salesforce or external) and then link to it. I don't think you can do anything else with email.